# Smart Client Software Factory : GAT Uninstall

Tags: guidance-automation-tool

I downloaded the Guidance Automation Toolkit for VS 2008 and in the middle of the install there was an error forcing it to close. Now whenever i re-run the GuidanceAutomationToolkitForVS2008.msi it tells me that the toolkit is already installed and I need to remove it before installing that one. I have no prior installs and can't find the GAT in the remove programs window. **Is there a way to remove this install with regedit for the Feb 2008 GAT for Visual Studio 2008?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Delete everything from all TEMP folders.
2. Dig around in regedit in both local machine and current user hives under the VS9.0 section. Search for GAT or Guidance Automation Toolkit and record the GUID's. Then search for those GUID's and delete all references, then finally delete all those entries found when searching for 'GAT'.
3. Finally, run devenv /setup, to 're-initialize' itself.

You can also try the Service Pack Preparation tool released for VS SP1.

Not sure if this will help, but hopes it provides some insight  :)

Good luck!